# Scrapy doesn't go to the next url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

the next_page variable gives the correct link when used on shell and even when printed on Console but Scrapy still keeps scraping the same(first) page

code below:

```py
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Bider"
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            "https://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/bottomwear/pr?sid=clo,vua&p[]=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DMen&p[]=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3Dmen&otracker=categorytree&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_1064313a-7a8d-48f3-8199-daaf60d62ef6_2_372UD5BXDFYS_MC.8HARX8UX7IX5&otracker=hp_rich_navigation_2_2.navigationCard.RICH_NAVIGATION_Fashion~Men%2527s%2BBottom%2BWear_8HARX8UX7IX5&otracker1=hp_rich_navigation_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_NA_NAV_EXPANDABLE_navigationCard_cc_2_L1_view-all&cid=8HARX8UX7IX5"
        ]
        for url in urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
        
        browser=webdriver.Chrome()
        
        browser.get(response.request.url) 

        next_page=response.css("a._1LKTO3::attr(href)").getall()
        try:
            next_page=next_page[-1]
        except:
            time.sleep(1)
            next_page=response.css("a._1LKTO3::attr(href)").getall()
            next_page=next_page[-1]
        print("\n\n\n NEXT PAGE\n\n\n")
        print("\n"+next_page+"\n")
        print(response.urljoin(next_page))
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page=response.urljoin(next_page)
            # yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page,callback=self.parse)

            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me so I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you. Anyway this pagination also works but it's cleaner.

```py
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Bider"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            "https://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/bottomwear/pr?sid=clo,vua&p[]=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DMen&p[]=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3Dmen&otracker=categorytree&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_1064313a-7a8d-48f3-8199-daaf60d62ef6_2_372UD5BXDFYS_MC.8HARX8UX7IX5&otracker=hp_rich_navigation_2_2.navigationCard.RICH_NAVIGATION_Fashion~Men%2527s%2BBottom%2BWear_8HARX8UX7IX5&otracker1=hp_rich_navigation_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_NA_NAV_EXPANDABLE_navigationCard_cc_2_L1_view-all&cid=8HARX8UX7IX5"
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.get(response.request.url)

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[span[text()="Next"]]/@href').get()
        
        if next_page:
            print("\n\n\n NEXT PAGE\n\n\n")
            print("\n"+next_page+"\n")
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            print(next_page)
            
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

[image: pagination proof]